# Sending messages to specific users in Teams using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Any endpoint for sending messages to specific users in Teams via the Graph API?

Comment: Q: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @FoggyDay The send method in the ChatMessage Resource only allows sending messages to a channel but not a specific user. I would like to send private messages to specific users. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielAdu-Djan, You can send message to specific user via graph API from a bot. First you need to create a conversation between the user and the bot via API. Then you can use that conversation id to send message to user.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Thanks, but is there a way with the graph API without using a bot?

Comment: As @DanielAdu-Djan mentioned earlier, using graph API you can only send message to a channel but not a personal message.

Answer (score 2):

(Edited because of clarity and added Custom-Requests)

You can send messages via Graph API to private users **BUT** there is a problem that you can't create a new chat between two users via the Graph API. This means that if you want to send a message from a user to a user, the chat must already exist. (Messages must first have been exchanged via the MSTeams client for a chat to exist)

So make sure that you have a open chat!

If so, have a look at this MSDoc (This document explains how you can list chats from a user): 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

After you have all your chats listed, you can have a look at this MSDoc (This document explains how you can send a message to a user):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Pay attention to the permissions! For sending messages and listing chats there are only delegated permissions so far ***AND*** these calls are only available in **BETA**, so be carefull with it.

---

I can only provide you Java code for an example.

(For everything I do I use ScribeJava to get an Auth-Token)
For delegated permissions you need to have a "User-Auth-Token". That means you have to use a Password-Credential-Grant like this:

```
private void _initOAuth2Service() 
{
    oAuth2Service = new ServiceBuilder(clientId)
            .apiSecret(clientSecret)
            .defaultScope(GRAPH_SCOPE)
            .build(MicrosoftAzureActiveDirectory20Api.custom(tenantId));


    //PASSWORD CREDENTIALS FLOW
    try 
    {
        oAuth2Token = oAuth2Service.getAccessTokenPasswordGrant(username, password);
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();  }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

username and password are the credentials from the user you want to send a message (sender).

---

**Initial situation**

This is my TeamsClient:

[image: My Teams Chat Section]

**ScribeJava**

---

**Get all open chats**

("me" in the URL is the user from above (sender).)

```
private Response _executeGetRequest()
{
final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats");
        oAuth2Service.signRequest(oAuth2Token, request);
        return oAuth2Service.execute(request);
}
```

The response I get from this request looks like this:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#chats","value":[{"id":"{PartOfTheID}_{firstHalfOfUserID}-e52a55572b49@unq.gbl.spaces","topic":null,"createdDateTime":"2020-04-25T09:22:19.86Z","lastUpdatedDateTime":"2020-04-25T09:22:20.46Z"},{"id":"{secondUserChatID}@unq.gbl.spaces","topic":null,"createdDateTime":"2020-03-27T08:19:29.257Z","lastUpdatedDateTime":"2020-03-27T08:19:30.255Z"}]}
```

You can see that I have two open chats and get two entries back from the request.

**Get the right conversatonID**

You have to know that the id can be split in three sections. {JustAPartOfTheId}_{userId}@{EndOfTheId}. The {userId} is the id from your chatpartner (recipient).

This is a GraphExplorer response which gives me all users and all informations about them.

[image: User Franz Bauer]

Now you can see that the first ID:
"id":"{PartOfTheID}_{firstHalfOfUserID}-e52a55572b49@unq.gbl.spaces"

matches the UserID after the "_".

You can split the ID at the "_" filter and find the ID you need.

**Send Message to user**

Now you know the right Id and can send a new request for the message like this:

```
final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{PartOfTheID}_{firstHalfOfUserID}-e52a55572b49@unq.gbl.spaces/messages");
        oAuth2Service.signRequest(oAuth2Token, request);
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.setPayload("{\"body\":{\"content\":\" " + "Hi Hi Daniel Adu-Djan" + "\"}}");
        oAuth2Service.execute(request);
```

---

**GraphAPI-Custom-Requests**

In the Graph-SDK is no opportunity to use the beta endpoint except for Custom-Requests. (For these requests I also use ScribeJava to get an Auth-Token)

**Set the BETA-Endpoint**

When you want to use the BETA-Endpoint you have to use the setEndpoint() function like this:

```
IGraphServiceClient graphUserClient = _initGraphServiceUserClient();
//Set Beta-Endpoint 
graphUserClient.setServiceRoot("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");
```

**Get all chats**

```
try
    {
      JsonObject allChats = graphUserClient.customRequest("/me/chats").buildRequest().get();
    }
catch(ClientException ex) { ex.printStacktrace(); }
```

**Same response like above**

**Same situation with the userId => split and filter**

**Send message**

```
IGraphServiceClient graphUserClient = _initGraphServiceUserClient();
//Set Beta-Endpoint again
graphUserClient.setServiceRoot("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta"); 
try
    {
      JsonObject allChats = graphUserClient.customRequest("/chats/{PartOfTheID}_{firstHalfOfUserID}-e52a55572b49@unq.gbl.spaces/messages").buildRequest().post({yourMessageAsJsonObject});
    }
catch(ClientException ex) { ex.printStacktrace(); 
}
```

---

Here is a little GIF where you can see that I didn't type anything. I just started my little application and it sends messages automatically.

[image: Send Message Gif]

I hope this helps you. Feel free to comment if you don't understand something! :)

Best regards!

Answer (score -1):

As of now, We do not have any endpoint to send messages to specific users via Graph API.

You may submit/vote a feature request in the UserVoice or just wait for the update from the Product Team.

You can vote for a below feature requests which are already created. All you have to do is enter your email ID and vote.

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/40642198-create-new-1-1-chat-using-graph-api

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/39139705-is-there-any-way-to-generate-chat-id-by-using-grap

**Update**:

Please find below one more user voice created for the same in Microsoft Graph user voices and vote for it.

https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37802836-add-support-for-creating-chat-messages-on-the-user

Comment: @iikkoo: It sounds like Pravin is speaking from an authoritative perspective. And instead of just saying "No, this isn't supported", he's offering options for the OP (and others interested in this endpoint) to request this feature. It doesn't _resolve_ the question, but it certainly _addresses_ it.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Yes exactly. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @iikkoo According to me, developers will have an option to vote for the feature requests (since the required functionality is not available) in the Microsoft User Voices platform from Stack overflow so that the required functionality would be available in the future. I request to have this answer here which can be helpful. Please suggest any edits. :)

Comment: @Jeremy Caney You are right. I removed the comment.